# Rails what css file call media="all"?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

```
media="all"
.navbar {
  border-radius:4px;
}
```

this is called by localhost in rails 4

this change my navbar, i want to remove this.

I found this code in all .css files but i couldn't find it~

where is this code called?

plz help me~!

if i delete

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

in application.html.erb

it didn't appear.

I want to make navbar border-radius:0px;~

Could you let me know how to solve this problem?

in chrome elements styles tabs

```
media="all"
.navbar {
border-radius: 4px;
}
.navbar-inverse {
border: none;
border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar {
border-radius: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
background: #151515;
padding: 15px 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-inverse {
background-color: #222;
border-color: #080808;
}
```

Comment: This is from Bootstrap. If you want to override `border-radius` then do that in your `application.css`, which should be loaded after Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

> Rails what css file call media="all"?

The attribute ***"media=all" is a css attribute which means that the css style will be included for all the medias like when browsing the website, printing the screen, etc***. You can find more information about the media attributes [`here`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html).

> this change my navbar, i want to remove this.

As `@Jordan` pointed out in comment since ***you are using twitter-bootstrap so this style is most probably coming from its stylesheet***

**Fix**

*Make a new css file which contains your navbar style and **import it below your bootstrap file so it'll override your bootstrap style***

```
#some_file.css.scss
.navbar{border-radius:0;}

#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "some_file";
```

**Update**

If this doesn't work for you then try to increase the [`css specificity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your navbar, this method doesn't depend upon where your style is present, style with higher specificity always overrides the style with lower ones, so if you have multiple class or id on your navbar you can do like this:

```
#all.css.scss
.navbar.some_other_class_on_navbar#some_id_on_navbar { border-radius: 0;}
```

*If even this doesn't work then there is an easy way to fix it(**you should use it only when you can't find anything else to override your style**):*

```
#all.css.scss
.navbar{border-radius: 0 !important;}
```

Comment: #all.css.scss
.navbar{border-radius:0;}

Comment: #app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
import "bootstrap-sprockets";
import "bootstrap";
import "all";

Comment: #app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all","data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

Comment: it cause some errors, and i remove

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all","data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

but it didn't override .navbar{border-radius:4px;}

Comment: media="all" called by localhost overwrite .navbar {border-radius:4px} latest

Comment: @권경덕 It's hard to understand here. Can you edit your question and post what you did?

Comment: @권경덕 checkout update. ***Use important option only when you can't find anything else to override it**, although in your case it should have work without !important* but still thought you should know about it as well

Answer (score 0):

```
# all.css.scss 
.navbar{border-radius:0;}


# app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "all";
```

I write this code but it also have 4px border-radius.
Maybe Rails bootstrap call it later.

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

if i delete javascript include tag in application.html.erb, media="all" didn't call.
but make an authentication token error...